# JS inserting content multiple times

Tags: javascript, loops, aurelia

I am working on a function to only show a specified number of rows and have a toggle button to display all rows. The issue I am running into is that if I have multiple tables on a page, the toggle button will display multiple times. If there are two tables, two buttons display after each table. If there are three, three buttons will display after each table.

I think I know the line of code that is doing this but for the life of me I cannot figure this out. I tried `insertAfter.forEach(table, toggleBar);` but it didn't work.

```
  attached() {
    // Insert element after another
    function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
      referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }

    // Set multiple attributes on an element
    function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
      for (let key in attrs) {
        el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
      }
    }

    // Toggle the rows on this table
    function toggleRows(table, rows, count) {
      // Loop through all the rows and toggle the hidden attribute
      for (let i = count; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].hidden ? rows[i].hidden = false : rows[i].hidden = true;
      }
    }

    // Gather all the tables to truncate based on the data-truncate attribute
    let truncatedTables = document.querySelectorAll('[data-truncate="true"]');

    // For each table to truncate
    truncatedTables.forEach(function(table) {
      let visibleRowCount = table.dataset.displayRows;
      let rows            = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
      let toggleBar       = document.createElement('div');
      let toggle          = document.createElement('button');
      let toggleText      = '+ ' + (rows.length - visibleRowCount) + ' More';

      // Truncate the table
      for (let i = visibleRowCount; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].hidden = true;
      }

      // Style the toggle-bar and set appropriate attributes
      toggleBar.className = 'toggle-bar';
      toggleBar.append(toggle);
      setAttributes(toggle, {
        'role'         : 'button',
        'aria-expanded': 'false',
        'aria-controls': table.id,
        'data-action'  : 'rowToggle',
        'data-text'    : '+ More',
        'data-alttext' : '- Less'
      });

      // Edit the toggle text & alt text attribute
      toggle.innerText = toggleText;
      toggle.dataset.text = toggleText;

      // Add the toggleBar after this table
      insertAfter(table, toggleBar);

      // When clicking the toggle
      toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Toggle the button based on aria-expanded attribute
        if ( this.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'false' ) {
          this.innerText = this.dataset.alttext;
          this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
        } else {
          this.innerText = this.dataset.text;
          this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        }

        // Toggle the table rows
        toggleRows(table, rows, visibleRowCount);
      });
    });
  }
```

I am using Aurelia so my view is very simple. I am just passing in some bindable properties.

```
<template>
<table data-truncate="${tableTruncate}" data-display-rows="${tableRows}" id="${tableId}">...
</table>
</template>
```

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: I am using Aurelia and passing in a few binding properties so the view is pretty simple. I will add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the most likely culprit is your `attached` function being called multiple times. I'm guessing that this is an event handler which is listening for tables to be attached to the document, or something like that, and that it's called once for each table, thus 3 tables would cause 3 buttons to be added.

There are a couple ways around this. You could change how frequently `attached` is called; you could set a flag on a table if it's already got a toggle button and skip it; or you could check if the toggle button already exists and update it.

Comment: Thanks @jdb. This is very helpful and yes, it seems that the "attached" is the issue (or at least part of the issue). My query selector `document.querySelectorAll('[data-truncate="true"]')` also seems to be a bit too broad. Back to the drawing board. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem wendee. Feel free to upvote the answer to indicate to others that it was helpful.